# Flask not opening SQLite Database on apache2

Tags: python, sql, apache, flask, ubuntu-server

I have been moving my flask apps from replit to my server, and things have been going smoothly, but I am moving my first app with SQL in it over to the server, and there keeps being errors when I open the database in the code. In the Apache error log, it says:
`sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file`
The app works well on replit, the database is in the same folder, but it doesn't work. Does anybody know why? I am using Ubuntu Server 20.04

Answer (score 1):

OnlyTrueJames is rigth,

> The database was in the same dir as init.py, but wsgi calls it as a module in a different dir, so it wasn't calling the db. Adding an absolute path eg.

The correct way is get the BASE_DIR var and use like that:

```
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'yoursqlite.db',
}
```

Djando makes the BASE_DIR

```
from pathlib import Path
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
```

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out why it's not working! The database was in the same dir as **init**.py, but wsgi calls it as a module in a different dir, so it wasn't calling the db. Adding an absolute path eg. /var/www/theapp/theapp/database.db works.